# Problem Taking a Derivative using Einstein Notation

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-fields, index-notation

At some point of an electrodynamics exercise, I had to prove:

$$ \nabla \frac{1}{|\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}'|} = - \frac{\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}'}{|\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}'|^3}$$

So, using Einstein Notation, I proceeded as follows:

$$\nabla [ (x_k - x_k')^2]^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} [ (x_k - x_k')^2]^{-\frac{1}{2}} \textbf{e}_i = \ ...$$

and now the part I think I am getting wrong
$$... \ (-1/2) [(x_k - x_k')^2]^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cdot 2\cdot (x_k-x_k') \cdot \frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_i} \textbf{e}_i = $$

$$- [(x_k - x_k')^2]^{-\frac{3}{2}} (x_k - x_k') \delta_{ki} \textbf{e}_i = $$
$$ - [(x_i - x_i')^2]^{-\frac{3}{2}} (x_i - x_i') \textbf{e}_i = $$
$$- \frac{(x_i - x_i') \textbf{e}_i}{[(x_i - x_i')^2]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

which of course is not the quantity of the second-hand side. The quantity derived would be correct if it had a different index on the denominator, but the Kronecker delta reduced the double sum to a single sum. What did I do wrong?

$\textbf{Edit 1: Clarification}$

The operator nabla above is:
$$\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \textbf{e}_i$$
and the vectors $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{r}'$ are respectively:
$$\textbf{r} = x_i \textbf{e}_i \text{ and } \textbf{r}' = x_i' \textbf{e}_i$$

Comment: In the very beginning you are not summing over $k$, are you?

Comment: I am. If I expanded that, it would be:

$$\nabla [(x_k - x_k')^2]^{-3/2} = \nabla [(x_1 - x_1')^2 + (x_2 - x_2')^2 + (x_3 + x_3')^2 ]^{-3/2}$$

Comment: I think the confusing is in using $k$ twice for different purposes in the first line of your second calculation. You have to use a different index because you don't want to sum over that $k$. At least not with respect to $|r-r'|$. Not sure if it is clear what I mean?!

Comment: Yes. Those are exactly my thoughts. I think this is correct:

$$... = (-1/2) [(x_j - x_j')^2]^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cdot 2\cdot (x_k-x_k') \cdot \frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_i} \textbf{e}_i = - [(x_j - x_j')^2]^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cdot (x_k-x_k') \cdot \delta_{ki} \textbf{e}_i  \ ...$$
where $j$ is a new index that runs in the set $\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\partial_i|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime|^2=\partial_i[(x_k-x_k^\prime)(x_k-x_k^\prime)]=2(x_k-x_k^\prime)\partial_i(x_k-x_k^\prime)=2(x_k-x_k^\prime)\delta_{ik}=2(x_i-x_i^\prime),$$the chain rule gives$$\partial_i|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime|^{-1}=-\frac12|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime|^{-3}\partial_i|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime|^2=-|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime|^{-3}(x_i-x_i^\prime).$$This is the desired $i$th component.

Answer (score 0):

Already when you write $|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}| = [(x_k-x_k')^2]^{-1/2}$ you get it wrong if you add a summation in front of the expression:
$$
\sum_k [(x_k-x_k')^2]^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{|x_1-x_1'|} + \cdots + \frac{1}{|x_n-x_n'|}.
$$

You need to learn to know when you can apply the Einstein summation convention.

---

One way to do the calculations:

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|} 
&= (\mathbf{e}^i \partial_i) \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|} \\
&= (\mathbf{e}^i \partial_i) \left((\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}')^2\right)^{-1/2}
\\
&= \mathbf{e}^i \, (-\frac12)\, \left((\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}')^2\right)^{-3/2} \left(2(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}')\cdot\partial_i(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}')\right) \\
&= -\mathbf{e}^i \, |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|^{-3} \left((\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}')\cdot\mathbf{e}_i\right) \\
&= -\mathbf{e}^i \, |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|^{-3} (x_i - x'_i) \\
&= -|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|^{-3} (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}') \\
&= -\frac{\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|^{3}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: By writing, $|\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}'|^{-1} = [(x_k - x_k')^2]^{-1/2}$, I mean:

$$|\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}'|^{-1} = \left(\sum_{k=1}^3 (x_k - x_k')^2 \right)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: But the Einstein summation convention is about skipping outer summation symbols. What I wrote is how your expression would be interpreted under the convention.

Comment: Anyways, I don't think that is the source of error in my proof. The essence is that I knew what the quantities I was writing down meant. I think the problem is that when I take the derivative of the sum, like:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \left( \sum_{k=1}^3 (x_k - x_k')^2 \right)^{-1/2}$$
It evaluates to
$$- \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{j=1}^3 (x_j - x_j')^2 \right)^{-3/2} \cdot 2 \cdot (x_k - x_k')$$
where $j$ is a new index.

Comment: Which is the correct result.